XSLT error UncheckedXPathException- invalid floating point value
I'm using XSLT map to get a value from the source and passing it to a target XML
I'm getting this error below, the value is MMTN2FE/A
net.sf.saxon.trans.UncheckedXPathException: invalid floating point value: MMTN2FE/A
Please advise what could be the adjustment that needs to be done to read this value properly. It seems the symbol '/' is causing the error.
Thank you!
To read the value MMTN2FE/A and pass it to the target XML

Adjustment to what exactly? You haven't posted any code. Please provide a [mcve] showing an example of the input XML, your current XSLT and the expected output. Also state which XSLT processor you are using (you tagged your question as xslt 1.0 yet it seems it's a Saxon processor??).

if you are trying to write a division, use the div operator
